# How to give parameter values in jquery url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, curl

```
$('#add').click(function(){

            $.jeegoopopup.open({
                url: 'update.php?cids= <?php echo $dt['callerid'] ?> && eid= <?php echo $dt['eid'] ?> && sts= <?php echo $dt['status'] ?>',
                width: 500,
                height: 200,
                center: true,
                skinClass: 'jg_popup_round', 
                resizable: false,
                scrolling: 'no',
```

If i give parameter values in url, the button not performing action

can any one help me

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: As well as the fabulous answers below, you should `urlencode()` the values you're echoing to ensure they do not break the request string

Comment: i am new to jquery, can you guide me how urlencode() works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

`&& is WRONG in Query string , its only & . The && operator comes ONLY in logical operations like a==2 && b==2`

Use proper quotes like following in JS Ajax code to concatenate PHP cariables.

```
url: 'update.php?cids='+<?php echo $dt['callerid'] ?>+'&eid='+<?php echo $dt['eid'] ?>+'&sts='+<?php echo $dt['status'] ?>,
```

Comment: when i click on button, it should get the cid, edi, status values with in the page of a particular member and pass them in next page..  i'm using the to update user details

Comment: @Mahendar pls  check where URL is going thru ajax in Console panel or any error . If any error post here.

Comment: @Mahendar , Hi what was the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Double quotes instead of single quotes in start and end like this

```
url: "update.php?cids= <?php echo $dt['callerid'] ?> && eid= <?php echo $dt['eid'] ?> && sts= <?php echo $dt['status'] ?>"
```

and check your console also for errors

Comment: 'echo "<input id='add' type='button' class='button' value='Pending' />";' When click on this button it is not performing any action , if i do as u said

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the spaces after `=` and lookout for quotes and make a single `&` ampersands too:

```
url: 'update.php?cids=<?php echo $dt["callerid"] ?>&eid=<?php echo $dt["eid"] ?>&sts=<?php echo $dt["status"] ?>',
//--------------------^----------------------------^^---^-----------------------^^---^
```

There are issues with :

1. Quotes
2. `&&` double ampersands.
3. space after `=`